# How to handle shopping cart and payment in an android app?

Tags: java, php, android

I have an app i am writing and i have code to implement a shopping car, that is add products to a list/database when the user clicks a buy button and display that list to them.

The problem is i don't know how to implement the payment process is there some sought of middle ware or API i can use to achieve this.
I was thinking i would send the card data to my website which has a PHP script to link that API or middle ware for the transaction.

all help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many payment gateways are available. You can use the PayPal sdk for this. PayPal have Android sdk.

Please check below links

Sdk https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/

and

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

Doc https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/

Some links [Shopping Cart API for any payment gateway? (PayPal at least required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321554/shopping-cart-api-for-any-payment-gateway-paypal-at-least-required?rq=1)

Ex: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-integrating-paypal-using-php-mysql-part-2/
and

http://androiddevelopmentanddiscussion.blogspot.in/2014/05/paypal-integration-in-android.html

Comment: Hello  satya is there a way to do what i need without Paypal i mean with countries that don't have Paypal. like directly to the users bank account.